# sleep system call on Linux - interaction with signals

Tags: linux-kernel, signals, sleep

I have a question about the documentation of sleep, on Linux OS.

[man 3 sleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) says:

> regarding thread safety, `sleep()` is "MT-Unsafe sig:SIGCHLD/linux",
>   which means that on Linux `sleep()` may temporarily install a signal
>   handler for `SIGCHLD` signal.

However, the same documentation says that "On Linux, `sleep()` is implemented via `nanosleep(2)`."

This is confirmed by [sleep implementation](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/sleep.c) inside the GNU Standard Library.

[man 2 nanosleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) says:

> "POSIX.1 explicitly specifies that it (`nanosleep`) does not interact
>   with signals". Nanosleep can be interrupted by "delivery of a signal
>   that triggers the invocation of a handler in the calling thread" (from
>   nanosleep manual).

So the question is:

is there a documentation problem with `sleep(3)` on Linux?

It seems to me that the documentation which says "MT-Unsafe sig:SIGCHLD/linux" is not correct, since on Linux `sleep(3)` uses `nanosleep(2)` which does not interfere with `SIGCHLD`, per the `nanosleep(2)` documentation.

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments from the texinfo [source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=manual/time.texi;h=bfa46dd45b78b5c95293584a05597be4831b04ed;hb=484b7af3ccb782ccb3491b541a68de9c5d6f063b#l2817) are a bit more explicit:

```
@deftypefun {unsigned int} sleep (unsigned int @var{seconds})
@standards{POSIX.1, unistd.h}
@safety{@prelim{}@mtunsafe{@mtascusig{:SIGCHLD/linux}}@asunsafe{}@acunsafe{}}
@c On Mach, it uses ports and calls time.  On generic posix, it calls
@c nanosleep.  On Linux, it temporarily blocks SIGCHLD, which is MT- and
@c AS-Unsafe, and in a way that makes it AC-Unsafe (C-unsafe, even!).
```

Except that it's a lie; `sleep(3)` on Linux will not block `SIGCHLD`; that's just a leftover from an old workaround ([removed in 2015](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/8c873bf0190740ac1102e13ff7aeb6c08048abfd)) for an even older Linux bug (fixed in 2.6.32).

This is the [commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blobdiff;f=manual/time.texi;h=56eada82a4ffede1209ec54cda9b24e2098f5aee;hp=5b6e0989d7984d4df7d9cd7e2d3342be0f6efabd;hb=23e5b8cb1ba7a31450bda75e3f06b7c76e175db4;hpb=11087373a6e329247fae279879aeba662c4aa99b) which introduced that language:

```
* manual/time.texi: Document MTASC-safety properties.
author  Alexandre Oliva <aoliva@redhat.com> 
    Sat, 1 Feb 2014 04:51:51 +0000 (02:51 -0200)
committer   Alexandre Oliva <aoliva@redhat.com> 
    Sat, 1 Feb 2014 04:51:51 +0000 (02:51 -0200)
commit  23e5b8cb1ba7a31450bda75e3f06b7c76e175db4
```

Comment: good suggestion, I am going to submit a bug report for man-pages.

Comment: link to bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204061

Comment: `sleep(3) on Linux will not block SIGCHLD, and I don't see any reason for it ever doing that.` but it did: https://github.com/sgallagher/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sleep.c#L84 . It was fixed in commit: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/8c873bf0190740ac1102e13ff7aeb6c08048abfd

Comment: @KamilCuk you're right, thanks. I've removed my speculations from the answer, and added that link instead.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who has more experience with Linux internals may correct me, but from the surrounding documentation it looks like they want to reserve the right to implement `sleep()` via `alarm()`, which would temporarily install a handler for `SIGALRM`.

This isn't the `SIGCHLD` mentioned in the actual documentation, but it would still fall under "MT-Unsafe sig".